# Extended Star LAN topology for a proposed network, is it suitable? See picture

Tags: networking, cisco-router

[Logical Extended Star LAN Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksCxy.png)

Is this a suitable logical topology? The assignment is to design a LAN for a campus.

The campus has a main building with 2 floors and about 80 computers across 2 floors.

Then there are 2 adjacent buildings, west and east buildings which also have two floors and about 60 computers per building.

[Physical topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmtng.jpg)

Is this a suitable physical topology? Are we on the right track?

Looking for some feedback from people in the field who do this kind of stuff regularly.

Please advise...

Any feedback is welcome

Comment: Suitable for what purpose?

Comment: Computer Network coursework

Comment: Each building can work on one subnet and then you need to (apparently) connect the buildings. You would want guest access. The network diagram looks complicated to me. Most of my small business work was in one building but the same number of people / devices.

Comment: What about WLAN? Where is the network diagram to assign the subnets? Subnet size? (And of course the point of the coursework is to learn from what you did, so I am sure you'll get feedback on your solution).